# How can I convert clojure.contrib.monads to be used with clojurescript?

Tags: clojure, monads, clojurescript

I would like to use the Clojure Monad library clojure.contrib.monads in ClojureScript. Is there an implementation that has been tested as known to work with ClojureScript as it does not appear in the standard ClojureScript distribution?

(I am assumming I may have to just copy and paste the code from a clj into a cljs. Although what about the macros, as these need to be in a clj file)

### Update: (am I right in thinking that these are the two files I will need?)

Files

- [monads.clj](https://github.com/richhickey/clojure-contrib/blob/master/src/main/clojure/clojure/contrib/monads.clj)
- [monadic_io_streams.clj](https://github.com/richhickey/clojure-contrib/blob/master/src/main/clojure/clojure/contrib/monadic_io_streams.clj)

Ok, it looks like this doesn't exist. I'm going to have to go through the implementation in Clojure first to make sure that eval and similar stuff is not used, as Clojurescript does not support all the features of Clojure.

Comment: I think you have the right approach

Comment: I would take a peek at the new version of the monad library at https://github.com/clojure/algo.monads/.

Comment: How is the Algo Monads library related to clojure.contrib.monads? Is it a fork or is it a totally different version?

Comment: `algo.monads` is definitely the way to go — the code in the Clojure contrib repo you linked to seems to be abandoned in favor of the new library.

Comment: Ok thanks Hans. I've put a bounty on the question just in case someone has already done the conversion to Clojurescript (as I won't have time for a couple of weeks)

Comment: Ok, it looks like this doesn't exist. I'm going to have to go through the implementation in Clojure first to make sure that eval and similar stuff is not used, as Clojurescript does not support all the features of Clojure.

Comment: For future reference, all of the "old" clojure.contrib stuff was deprecated but many of the libraries were migrated to new namespaces and are still maintained (some with a new API, some with the original API). This page is a good reference: http://dev.clojure.org/display/design/Where+Did+Clojure.Contrib+Go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to take a look at Jim Duey's [protocol-monads](https://github.com/jduey/protocol-monads), for which cljs support has been recently added - see [this commit](https://github.com/jduey/protocol-monads/commit/224a15135bd721fb81f22afca53dc6ae92754416) for details.